# Core Data Concurrency Import Performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, core-data, concurrency

I’m working on an app connected to a web service which retrieves lot of data during app launch. I use concurrency to avoid UI blocking. I choosed the following Core Data Stack pattern : background private moc —> main moc —> writer private moc —> coordinator —> file.

The problem occures when operations are being imported. The CPU is 100% used and the app gets slow along the process. I work with batches of 300 objects for a total import of about 10,000 objects.

For each batch, an NSOperation is created with an associated temporary moc, child of the background one. Operation is enqueue in an NSOperationQueue.
When the importing jobs are done, the app get even slower, depending on the number of jobs running. I also note that when the app is killed, and relaunched, it’s really way more usable and fast.

My memory footprint changes between 40Mo and 60Mo when importing. Do you think it’s too much?

Do you think my stack pattern is appropriate for my needs? Should I migrate to a stack with 2 coordinators?

Moreover, when fetching data to display in tableView, should I use performBlockAndWait to get data immediately before displaying the view ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Never have a writer go through the main moc to reach the coordinator.  You are losing all your performance gains when you save the stack.

Comment: Thanks for answering. So i should set background context child of writer context and let the main context directly link to the coordinator ? But according to @MattMorey, the writer should be parent of main  https://speakerdeck.com/player/360691a030570131a0a76af09d9fc329# wrong ?

Comment: @Avi, his writer context is not going through the main context.  Based on his description his stack is a normal parent child setup.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra, I meant the thread doing the import.  It's essentially the writer for this process.

Comment: @NicoC., my ideal core data stack doesn't use parent-child contexts.  I do writing in the background using a serial queue with throw-away contexts.  The main context only reads, and I merge changes when background contexts save.  All contexts are siblings, which means they all connect to the coordinator directly.  But a comment is not a good place to give the intricate details.

Comment: @Avi the child context is not a writer, it is a data processor that, when it saves, moves the changes (in memory only) through the main queue.  The main queue gets the updates of the changes and updates the UI, all without having to write merging code that, honestly, most people get wrong.  There is an insignificant performance difference between doing it this way (with less code) and the older way (with more code).  The writer is the private context at the bottom of the stack which is writing to disk asynchronously.

Comment: My stack works exactly as described by @MarcusS.Zarra. Actually you don't have to manually write the merge process between context by using notification. The parent/child pattern works as expected and like a charm

Answer (score 1):

Your stack as described is fine.

CPU usage can be misleading.  You want to make sure you are not on the main thread as that will cause most of your slowness and/or stuttering in the app.

When you watch your app in Instruments, what is taking the most time?  How much time is spent on the main queue?

In general, imports shouldn't be causing the CPU to sit at 100%.  If you are doing that from a background thread there is most likely some performance gains to be made.

If should share your import code and or Instruments trace so that I can see what is going on.

Comment: I will give you more details from instruments as soon as possible. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I think your setup is problematic. You state that the child of the background managed object context is main thread and that you create such children to import. This is bound to cause UI glitches.

Also, I believe that relying on `NSOperation` is unnecessary over-engineering. You should use the `NSManagedObjectContext` block APIs instead.

My recommended setup would be:

```
RootContext (background, writing to persistent store) -> parent of
MainContext (foreground, UI) -> parent of
WorkerContext(s) (background, created and discarded ad hoc)
```

You can create worker contexts in the callbacks of your web calls to do the heavy lifting for the import. Make sure you are using the block APIs and confine all objects to the local context. You `save` the context to push the changes up to the main thread (which can already start displaying data before it is saved to the store), and periodically, you save the main context and the writer context, always using the bock APIs.

A typical such `saveContext` function that can be called thread safe (here `self` refers to the data manager singleton or app delegate):

```
func saveContext () {
    if self.managedObjectContext.hasChanges  {
       self.managedObjectContext.performBlocAndWait {
            do { try self.managedObjectContext.save() }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print("Unresolved error while saving main context \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
        self.rootContext.performBlockAndWait {
            do { try self.rootContext.save() }
            catch let error as NSError {
                print("Unresolved error while saving to persistent store \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: My stack is identical to the one you refer. The only difference, i use workers as child of an existing background context (child of the main one). On the other hand, i'll try to remove NSOperation for import cause I think you're right concerning over-engineering. I also use block API for all work related to Core Data but i don't really like performBlockAndWait for saving method because I think blocking the calling thread is not necessary for that job, doesn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

After few days of test and instruments trace, I can give you more details. The following snippet shows how I save my context (based on parent/child pattern) from a shared instance :

```
- (void)save {
    [self.backgroundManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
        [self saveContext:self.backgroundManagedObjectContext];

        [self.mainManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
            [self saveContext:self.mainManagedObjectContext];

            [self.writerManagedObjectContext performBlock:^{
                [self saveContext:self.writerManagedObjectContext];
            }];
        }];
     }];
}

- (void)saveContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context {
     NSError *error = nil;

     if ([context hasChanges] && ![context save:&error]) {
         NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
     }
}
```

Then each import job is perform on the background context thank to a synchronous operation. The following method is fired in operation main.

```
- (void)operationDidStart
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.context;
    NSMutableArray *insertedOrUpdatedObjects = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSMutableArray *subJSONs = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSUInteger numberOfJobs = ceil((double)self.JSONToImport.count/self.batchSize);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfJobs; i++) {
        NSUInteger startIndex = i * self.batchSize;
        NSUInteger count = MIN(self.JSONToImport.count - startIndex, self.batchSize);
        NSArray *arrayRange = [self.JSONToImport subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(startIndex, count)];
        [subJSONs addObject:arrayRange];
    }

    __block NSUInteger  numberOfEndedJobs = 0;

    for (NSArray *subJSON in subJSONs) {
        [moc performBlock:^{
            [self startJobWithJSON:subJSON context:moc completion:^(NSArray *importedObjects, NSError *error) {

                numberOfEndedJobs++;

                if (!error && importedObjects && importedObjects.count > 0) {
                    [insertedOrUpdatedObjects addObjectsFromArray:importedObjects];
                }

                if (numberOfEndedJobs == numberOfJobs) {
                    [[CoreDataManager manager] save];

                    if (self.operationCompletion) {
                        self.operationCompletion(self, insertedOrUpdatedObjects, error);
                    }
                }
            }];
        }];
    }
}
```

As you can see, I segment my import in batches (of 500). The operation perform each batch on the background context queue and I save my stack when all batches are ended.

It seems the save method take 23% of CPU usage for each thread thanks to Time Profiler.

Hope to be as clear as possible.